# angular directive ng-if in angular-translate translation string not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using angularjs with angular-translate v2.6. I've got a translation that includes a `ng-if` directive. I've observed that the `ng-if` is ignored within the text.

I see angular-translate includes `translate-compile` but adding this declaration to the html like so has no effect:

```
'Interest.Explanation': 'This is called <a translate-compile 
   ng-show="interestEnabled" 
   href="/{{id}}/interest">interest</a> 
<span translate-compile 
      ng-hide="interestEnabled">interest</span>.'
```

Used in html like so

Any ideas? I'm really scratching my head on this one. (I'm also using ngSanitize if that makes a difference?)

Comment: It should work if you're using translate-compile. Show me your translations (containing html tags & angularjs directives)

Comment: @Shantanu I've updated the question.

Comment: @Shantanu I've just realised I have the `translate-compile` in the wrong place!!

Comment: That's the reason! Alternatively you can use $translateProvider.usePostCompiling(true); in config block so that it'll be applicable in whole application & you don't need to use translate-compile on every element (translation containing ng directives)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had `translate-compile` inside the wrong tag. Should be on the parent translate tag, not in the string itself.

```
<p><span translate-compile translate='Interest.Explanation' translate-values={...}</span></p>
```